# How to use mutable and immutable Sets in the same file, in Scala

Tags: scala, set

Given that default implementation of a Set is immutable:

```
val Set = immutable.Set
```

And in order to make it mutable one needs to import

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set;
```

In event one needs to use both mutable and immutable Sets in a given file, how should one go about it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you need to use both mutable and immutable collections in the same file, the canonical solution is just to prefix with `mutable` or `immutable` explicitly.

```
import collection._

val myMutableSet: mutable.Set[Int] = mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)
val myImmutableSet: immutable.Set[Int] = immutable.Set(1, 2, 3)
```

AS Kim Stebel mentioned in his answer, you can also use a renaming import:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set => MutableSet}
```

However `mutable.Set` is only one character more than `MutableSet`, and does not introduce any new name so you might as well just use the former form.

Answer (score 10):

You can rename symbols when you import them.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set => MutableSet}
```

Comment: Right. Say you have to use different Sets interchangeably throughout the program. How would you indicate to the compiler that *this* `Set` is a mutable one and *that* `Set` is not?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: You declare several variables in your .scala file and want var a = {mutable set}, var b = {immutable set}. How can this be done please?

Comment: var a = Set(...); var b = MutableSet(...)

Comment: `MutableSet` is not a class in Scala, is it?

Comment: That's why you need the renaming import.

Comment: `scala> import scala.collection.mutable.{Set => MutableSet}
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set=>MutableSet}

scala> MutableSet(1,2,3)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 1, 3)
`

Comment: Oh i see. Sorry, did not get it at first.

Comment: You can also just import the mutable symbol: `import collection.mutable` and then use `mutable.Set()`